# What does @ means

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

What does that `@`, in `data.@state` means?

```
<s:State name="normal" basedOn="{data.@state}"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: [e4x](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` is a [e4x](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) attribute identifier operators.

```
var myXML:XML =  
    <order> 
        <item id='1'> 
            <menuName>burger</menuName> 
            <price>3.95</price> 
        </item> 
        <item id='2'> 
            <menuName>fries</menuName> 
            <price>1.45</price> 
        </item> 
    </order>

trace(myXML.item[0].@id); // Output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, @ is an [e4x](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) attribute.

In the context you have provided, I must assume that data is an [XMLLst](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html).  But, it may be an [XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) variable.  In the context of Flex it may also be an [XMLListCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html); which is just a wrapper around an XMLList used as the dataProvider to a Flex listed-based class.

I assume that the data variable must point to something like this:

```
<someElement state="someStateValue"> </someElement>
```

And therefore, data.@state should return the value 'someStateValue'